# why does not python3 for loop overwrite variables?

Tags: python-3.x

for beginner type question but can somebody tell me why does python 3 dont overwrite the below variable
in this line output = output + s1/output = output + s2

in short can anyone tell inner workings of this==>output = output + s2
is it getting assign ref variable? or storing the value in it?

```
s=input("enter your string: ") #A132BC
S1='' 
S2=''
output=''
for x in s: 
    if x.isalpha():
        S1=S1 + x 
    else:
        S2=S2 + x 
for s1 in sorted(S1): 
    output = output + s1 #output = '' + A==>  output = 'A'
for s2 in sorted(S2):
    output = output + s2
print(output)
```

Comment: Did the answer helped?

Comment: @LouisLac Yes it certainly does that clarifies my concept as clear as crystal as i am learning python on my own so doubt/confusion is on every corner.

A Lots of Thanks to you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python everything is an object that is treated as references.

`S1 = ""` creates the value `""` and stores the reference into the name `S1`. If later you do `S1 = "Hello, world!`, the interpreter creates a new value an assigns this new reference to `S1`.

The same behaviour occurs for `output`, at first it stores a reference to "" and when you do `output = output + s1` a new value that is the concatenation of `output` and s1 is created and the new reference is assigned to `output`.

Not that this can be written in a more concise way as `output += s1`.

This [link](https://realpython.com/python-variables/) contains useful stuff about Python types an assignment.

---

## Note

As pointed out in the comments there is some subtleties with assignments, you can read [this](However, I'll update my answer concerning a missing note about mutable/immutable behaviour.) blog post for even more details.

An interesting and quite misleading behaviour for beginners pointed out is that there are differences in the use of operator `+=`.
For int, str or bool this operator effectively creates a new value from the old one, the original value is not mutated.
For sequences this operator behaves has a mutating operator.

For instance compare the output of those two functions:

```
def modify(int_value):
  int_value += 1  # Does not add 1 in-place

def modify(array):
  array += [1]  # Mutates the array in-place
```

Comment: "stores the reference into the name S1." => actually, no  the name is only a name (literally - a string), there's nothing "stored into" it. It's really a key=>value pair in a hashtable.

Comment: And THE reference article on Python's names and variables is https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Thank you for the precision but the hashable thing seems to be an implementation detail and the term "reference" is an appropriated concept to use here (it is used extensively throughout the article you linked). Also this article is a blog post, why should it be "the" reference? It'a a valuable article with lots of details but it is not the unique reference nor the official one.

Comment: I'll add details about mutable and immutable values in my answer as it could be misleading (int versus array for instance).

Comment: The hashtable thing is not that much of an implementation detail - CPython is actually not using a hashtable for functions locals FWIW - but the actual semantic of python's names to objects bindings. But I agree I should have wrote "mapping" instead.

Comment: And Ned Batchelder's article is commonly considered as the _de facto_ reference (no pun intended) on the topic, that's all. Everything it says is actually documented one way or another, but nowhere as clearly stated in one single piece. Here again sorry if it sounded like I wanted to criticize your answer, that was not the point.